# how to classify .txt documents into some other .txt categories by supervised learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, supervised-learning, document-classification

I've got about thousands of txt documents stored in 8 different file folders which are tagged with topic categories (actually,they are class 1,2,3...). And I have another 80 txt documents that don't yet have categories. I'm trying to find the best way to categorize them.

I have already finished the text segmentation and deleted the English letters(cause they are Chinese texts).What should I do next?

I can get the words with highest TF-IDF values but don't know how to do next.It seems like I should turn these text into vectors and train a classifier,but I don't know how.

Comment: Consider taking a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own bag of words models, you could use e.g. [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) from gensim. It offers excellent performance that will be difficult to match with your own implementation. You can choose between hierarchical softmax or negative sampling.